# $cordovaInAppBrowser not working on android with ngCordova and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, ngcordova

I'd want to use the `$cordovaInAppBrowser` plugin to open a YouTube window in my app.

I'm using ngCordova with Ionic. I tried this way :

```
 $scope.youtube = function () {

    var options = {
        location: 'yes',
        clearcache: 'yes',
        toolbar: 'no'
    };

    alert('option set');

    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://www.youtube.fr', '_blank', options)
          .then(function (event) {
              alert('success');
          })
          .catch(function (event) {
              alert('fail');
          });

}
```

This is working perfectly in a Chrome Browser when I do an `ionic serve android`, even though it doesn't display the alert functions when succeeding or fail function when failing, it opens a new page loaded with YouTube.
But this is not working at all on Android, nothing happens, and I got no error message in the console. I can't test it on iPhone cause I don't have one.
Has someone got an idea why it's behaving this way?

---

Ok, this is a piece of the Android log trace after building it for Android:

```
07-06 16:31:04.870  19469-19515/me.app.id I/App﹕ WARNING: Back Button Default Behavior will be overridden.  The backbutton event will be fired!

07-06 16:31:14.540  19469-19469/me.app.id D/SystemWebChromeClient﹕ file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js: Line 173 : No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

07-06 16:31:14.540  19469-19469/me.app.id I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

07-06 16:31:14.540  19469-19515/me.app.id D/PluginManager﹕ exec() call to unknown plugin: Console

07-06 16:31:24.530  19469-19469/me.app.id D/SystemWebChromeClient﹕ file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js: Line 173 : No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

07-06 16:31:24.530  19469-19469/me.app.id I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

07-06 16:31:24.540  19469-19515/me.app.id D/PluginManager﹕ exec() call to unknown plugin: Console

07-06 16:31:24.870  19469-19469/me.app.id D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 593K, 10% free 12440K/13676K, paused 13ms, total 15ms

07-06 16:31:24.880  19469-19469/me.app.id I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 15.263MB for 1127536-byte allocation

07-06 16:31:25.870  19469-19515/me.app.id D/PluginManager﹕ exec() call to unknown plugin: InAppBrowser
```

It looks like the plugin doesn't get to be called. But i checked twice, I'm calling it the good way :

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'azure-mobile-service.module', 'ngCordova']);
```

And in the controller :

```
    app.controller('PosterCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Azureservice', '$localstorage', '$ionicLoading', '$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaFile', '$cordovaInAppBrowser',
function ($scope, $location, Azureservice, $localstorage, $ionicLoading, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile, $cordovaInAppBrowser)
```

And the other ngCordova plugins work fine, but it looks like every plugin gets the `call to unknown plugin`.

Comment: Can you show an example of your log on android ? On device, it uses native code to open a chrome view, and on web it will use `window.open()`. That means your problem is on the native side of things

Comment: Actually, GapDebug doesn't write anything in the log console. Is there a log file i'm missing ?

Comment: You should use the android cli tool to tail the logs and filter it to display only logs from cordova or your app namespace

Comment: I edited my question with the log trace

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, my bad, I just messed with the versions.... The azure-mobile-services plugin required org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser, so it didn't install well the latest version. I just removed everything and added my plugins in the good order. Thanks !

Comment: Good to know you fixed your issue. You should mark this question as answered now :)